# Apply custom discount in grand total in create order magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, sales-order, order-grid, grand-total

i want to apply custom discount on grand total (without coupons) in create order section in magento admin.

i have added 2 lines code for check in this file
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Create\Items\Grid.php

in function

```
public function getSubtotal()
    {


        if ($this->displayTotalsIncludeTax()) {
            if ($address->getSubtotalInclTax()) {

                return $address->getSubtotalInclTax();

            }

            return $address->getSubtotal()+$address->getTaxAmount();
        } else {
             $address->setDiscountAmount(-(400));
     $address->setDiscountDescription('Custom Discount');




     $address->save();
     return $address->getSubtotal();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

but it is not only applied on subtotal of products not on grand total

[image: see here output of applied code]

Need help to find correct function.

Comment: what did u try?

Comment: @Manashvibirla just added two lines $address->setDiscountAmount(-(400));
     $address->setDiscountDescription('Custom Discount');  to check it. but it this $400 discount applied on subtotal only not on grand total . i think there is any other function to calculate grand total .

Comment: @AshviniMarwal Suppose if i want to enter discount price at order page how can i change.. Now your code looks like assigned discount order amount in code. i need change randomly so assigning discount amount in code is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed. issue was in get price with tax.

Comment: can you please add your code here i m also stuck with problem like you.Thanks

Comment: follow this article http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/

Comment: @Zaheerabbas Could you pls explain how you achieve this.

Comment: @Zaheerabbas what issue you are facing ?